# assign value from attribute_view_gui from select attribute

Tags: ezpublish

I have an attribute if type `select`. When i try to get value from this attribute content it gives the identification number instead of the value. I call like

```
$node.data_map.my_attribute_identifier.content
```

This is expected behaviour. https://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Reference/Datatypes/Selection

> Raw output
>   The ".content" of an ezcontentobjectattribute object using this datatype returns an array of the identification numbers (as strings) of the selected options.

I want the value not the identification number. I can get that using `attribute_view_gui`  like

```
attribute_view_gui attribute=$node.data_map.my_attribute_identifier
```

But i can't assign value to a variable this way. How can i assign value from a `select` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

First of all i recommend you to always check default templates in your ezpublish to figure out how should template look...

Maybe this example will help:

```
<input  
    id="whatever_id_you_like" 
    type="text" size="50" 
    name="ContentObjectAttribute_ezstring_data_text_{$node.object.data_map.YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_SHORT_NAME.id}" 
    value="{$YOUR_VAR}" 
/>
```

or u can use default view for attribute like this:

```
{attribute_view_gui attribute=$node.data_map.YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_SHORT_NAME}
```

also might be helpful - way to find correct path (sometimes you need add *".data_int"* or *".data_text"* on the end of the path to display data):

{**$path**|attribute(show,**depth**)} example:

```
{$node|attribute(show,2)}
```

or

```
{$YOUR_FANCY_VAR.content|attribute(show,2)}
```

Answer (score -1):

You may want to take a look at the view template of ezselection:
[ezselection.tpl](https://github.com/ezsystems/ezpublish-legacy/blob/master/design/standard/templates/content/datatype/view/ezselection.tpl)

This is the code that eZ Publish uses to view the data type.

content of ezselection.tpl:
`{let selected_id_array=$attribute.content}
{section var=Options loop=$attribute.class_content.options}
{section-exclude match=$selected_id_array|contains( $Options.item.id )|not}
{$Options.item.name|wash( xhtml )}{delimiter}<br/>{/delimiter}{/section}
{/let}`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank you for that advice, @LeftyX! I now added the content of ezselection.tpl.